# Overriding "Textboxes" dialog fields from the command line in MSI installer (Visual Studio 2010 Web Setup)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project, web-setup-project

### Background

I have a Web Setup project in Visual Studio 2010.

In the `User Interface` section, I have a custom `Textboxes` dialog. These text fields have property names like EDITA1, EDITA2.

I have a `Custom Action` which makes use of these properties:

```
CustomActionData = /foo="[EDITA1]" /bar="[EDITA2]" /zip="[BLARB]"
```

In the code for handling this custom action, these parameters are available in the `Context.Parameters` dictionary

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver) {
    string foo = Context.Parameters["foo"]; // originates in edit box EDITA1
    string bar = Context.Parameters["bar"]; // originates in edit box EDITA2
    string zip = Context.Parameters["zip"];
```

### Problem

I want to be able to run the installer from a script, without a UI, so I need to pass in values for `foo` and `bar` via the command line. The way you're supposed to do this is by appending `PROPERTY=VALUE` to your MSI command line, like this:

```
msiexec /qn /i MyInstaller.msi EDITA1=John EDITA2=Smith BLARB=Donut
```

But this doesn't work. Custom parameters which *aren't* associated with custom text fields *do* show up. For instance, `BLARB` gets passed through just fine (Parameters["zip"]=="Donut"). But properties which are associated with the text fields do not show up, as if they are being nuked by the empty (but hidden) dialog box before my custom install function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the dialog which overrides the property values. A log file will help you determining what causes the property value change.

Comment: The logfile makes no mention of property EDITA1, but does contain the following two lines: `15:15:44: CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1.`, `15:15:44: CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1. Return value 1.`.  This is very early in the log file, before any custom actions are invoked. That's what suggested to me that the installer is initializing those edit fields at startup.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the case. You will have to edit the MSI and condition the custom actions that reset the props not be executed when there is no UI

Comment: `CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1` is not my code. It happens *before* any custom actions are run. In fact, there is only one custom action, and it happens on commit.

Comment: Googling a bit I found this post on msdn forums. It seesms it depicts your situation exactly: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/b9529be2-ed0e-4c98-b201-f5e78c7e99b2/

Comment: Good find. Unfortunately, there's no solution proposed there. Fabiana thought the same thing I did "Seems command-line parameters are overwritten by 'default value' of custom dialog's controls, even if the default value is empty.". The workaround he/she came up with is something I thought of, but was trying to avoid.

Comment: I just implemented the workaround. Giving you credit for digging up that link. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Well i ran into the same issues and after lot testing and debugging following all the advise on the internet, found myself helpless till i got to read [this](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2006/12/04/Installer-Custom-Actions-and-Command-Line-Arguments.aspx#comment) post.

In the web setup project, set the value of 
`EDITA1 Value=[VARIABLE]`. In custom action , customdata set `/va=[EDITA1]`

Now when you install the application through command line you need to set `VARIABLE=data`.
When you run into the GUI, type the data in the textbox.

It works, i have tested and verified in the log file as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the InstallExecuteSequence in the generated MSI file has some custom actions such as CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1. If you look at this, it does in fact set the property value to null, even if you had specified it on the command line. To pass them from the command line into the MSI silently you'd need to  edit the MSI file (for example with Orca) to:

1. Delete the custom actions in the InstallExecuteSequence table with names like CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1.
2. In the Property table, the SecureCustomProperties value, add your edit properties all separated by colons. For example add ";EDITA1" to the existing list.